Vercel deployment Serverless Functions contain an invalid "runtime"
so i wanted to update my packages, and now my Vercel Log says, that "The following Serverless Functions contain an invalid "runtime": (index:14)". I use Node 18 in Vercel and locally. Where does the 14 come from? When i search for 14 in my project files, nothing appears.
Can someone help? What Functions are meant and how to set the version to 18?
[success] Generated /sitemap.xml
[info] Nuxt build took: 51263.316986 ms
[log]  ----------------- Install dependencies ----------------- 
yarn install v1.22.22
info No lockfile found.
[1/6] Validating package.json...
[2/6] Resolving packages...
[3/6] Fetching packages...
[4/6] Linking dependencies...
warning "@nuxtjs/sentry > @sentry/vue@7.110.1" has unmet peer dependency "vue@2.x || 3.x".
warning "nuxt-leaflet > vue2-leaflet@2.7.1" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^2.5.17".
warning " > vt-notifications@0.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^2.0.0".
warning " > vue-advanced-cropper@1.11.6" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^2.6.6".
warning "vue-ssr-carousel > bukwild-stylus-library@3.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "stylus@*".
warning "vue-ssr-carousel > bukwild-stylus-library > stylus-type-utils@0.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "stylus@0.x".
warning " > vuex-persist@3.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "vuex@>=2.5".
[5/6] Building fresh packages...
[6/6] Cleaning modules...
Done in 8.48s.
[info] Install dependencies took: 8706.237786 ms
[log]  ----------------- Collect artifacts ----------------- 
[info] Collect artifacts took: 17519.974892 ms
Build Completed in /vercel/output [3m]
Deploying outputs...
Error: The following Serverless Functions contain an invalid "runtime":
  - index (nodejs14.x). Learn More: https://vercel.com/guides/serverless-function-contains-invalid-runtime-error


You can change the node version of your vercel project to what you're using locally (18), dashboard -> project_name -> general -> and you should see the node version option
